# Can you order hql results based on matching restrictions?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have an object *Dog* which holds a set of *DogMetadata*.

Each DogMetadata has two values: a String ("*desc*") and an int ("*rank*").

Descriptions of dogs have different rankings such as: "small" is 5, "furry" is 2, "friendly" is 9, "dalmation" is 11, "mutt" is 22.

I need to search for dogs based on **any** of their desc values (for example, find "furry" OR "small" dogs).

This query returns the matching dogs, but they are not in any order.

```
select distinct Dog as d
left join d.dogMetadata as dMeta
where ( (dMeta.desc = 'furry') OR (dMeta.desc = 'small') )
```

How do I order the list of matching Dog objects by the total "rank" values of any matching DogMetadatas?

I've been working like a dog on this all day (trying "Group By" and "Order By") but I think I have been barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query won't work:

```
select d from Dog as d
left join fetch d.dogMetadata as dMeta
where ( (dMeta.desc = 'furry') OR (dMeta.desc = 'small') )
group by d
order by sum(dMeta.rank) desc
```

Because of this bug:
http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1615?focusedCommentId=24530#action_24530

I worked around this limitation by only requesting the Dog IDs:

```
select d.id from Dog as d
left join fetch d.dogMetadata as dMeta
where ( (dMeta.desc = 'furry') OR (dMeta.desc = 'small') )
group by d.id
order by sum(dMeta.rank) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from the top of my head (without actually verifying it in HQL)

```
from Dog d where d.dogMetadata.desc in ('furry','small','whatever') order by d.dogMetadata.rank
```

Comment: I did not know about the hql in clause.  That is very helpful, thank you.  Your answer (with some tweaking) /almost/ works;  I need to order Dogs who match multiple desc to rank higher in the list (based on the sum of the ranks).